# How these arguments of ajax function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I am whatching a tutorial that has the following code

[image]

But I can't understand what are `url`, `cache` and `success`? Are they arrays? How do they work?

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: $.ajax documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I am not in a proper place now, but I will do it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find below the explanations:

---

cache

> *Type: Boolean*
>   A Boolean value indicating whether the browser should cache the requested pages. Default is true.
>   If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. **Note:** Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.

url

> *Type: String*
>   Specifies the URL to send the request to. Default is the
>   current page

success(result,status,xhr)

> *Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )*
>   A function to be run when the request succeeds
>   A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the `dataType` parameter or the `dataFilter` callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

Everything is explained in the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Documentation